# How to speed up function in helm-dependent library

Tags: helm, edebug

I have found that the following function is taking up a massive amount of time (75%-85%) in a library I am working on. What is slowing it down? It uses cl-loop, but I don't think that is what is slowing it down. I have tried using Edebug but it is not helping.

The library is [here](https://github.com/attosaurus/helm-q.el/blob/master/helm-q.el#L121) if anyone wants to take a look.

```
(defun helm-asdf-get-instance-by-display (display-str)
  "Get an instance by its display string.
Argument DISPLAY-STR: the display string."
  (cl-loop with candidates = (helm-attr 'candidates)
           for candidate in candidates
           when (string= display-str (car candidate))
           return (cdr candidate)))
```

Comment: Have you tried profiling the code's execution to see where the most time is spent? [`(info "(elisp) Profiling")`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Profiling.html)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: @Basil yes, that is how I discovered that it usually takes 75% to 85% of the CPU time. Does anything stand out as being the culprit to you?

Comment: @attosaurus I'm not familiar with Helm, but at face value it looks most likely that either `helm-attr` is slow, or it returns a very large number of candidates, or both.

Comment: If you have the profile, why not add it to your question?